# System Restore Points Are Too Recent

Tags: windows-8.1

In order to troubleshoot a problem on my Windows 8.1 laptop, I want to use System Restore to undo system changes made in the last 3 days. However, the only restore point that shows up in the System Restore wizard is from less than 1 day ago; it is too new to have any chance of resolving the issue on my PC. This is strange to me because I know that years ago, I successfully did a restore using a restore point that was 6 months in the past. Why do I have so few restore options now? Is there another way that I can restore system files to their state from 3 days ago, or am I out of luck?

Comment: How many restore points a system might have entirely depends on the amount of storage you allocate to restore points.  If you don't have any restore points past 24 hours, then those restore points no longer exists, nothing can be done after the fact.

Comment: You can double-check if there are other System Restore Points points with a third-party tool such as System Restore Explorer, https://www.nicbedford.co.uk/files/InstallSystemRestoreExplorer.msi (BTW, it's an MSI, but just open in 7-Zip -- no need to install). Do you have an older disk image?

Comment: System Restore needs a certain amount of space and old restore points will automatically be deleted if there is not enough space on the disk. You can manually check if the restore points are there or not instructions here : https://www.google.com/amp/s/hetmanrecovery.com/recovery_news/system-restore-point-in-windows-10.htm/amp/